# how to interpolate workflow level variable into another workflow level variable github actions

Tags: github, scope, environment-variables, github-actions, variable-initialization

I'm new to github actions.

Below is my workflow:

```
name: Example

on: [push, workflow_dispatch]

env:
  APPNAME: 'myapp1'
  APPURL: "https://mybank/$APPNAME/widgets/hello.json" 

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - name: Print variables
        run: |
          echo "APPURL is: ${{ env.APPURL }}"
```

Output:

```
Run echo "APPURL is: https://mybank/$APPNAME/widgets/hello.json"
APPURL is: https://mybank//widgets/hello.json
```

I understand that `env.` cannot be used under at workflow level.

Is it possible to have variable interpolation `APPNAME` at workflow level i.e for `APPURL`?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the `windows-latest` runner using `powershell` by default to run command lines.

In that case, informing the `shell: bash` will work.

```
steps:
  - name: Print variables
    run: |
      echo "APPURL is: ${{ env.APPURL }}"
    shell: bash

# Will print: APPURL is: https://mybank/myapp1/widgets/hello.json
```

*Note that using the `ubuntu-latest` or `macos-latest` runners will work as well without informing the shell, as they use `bash` as default.*

I've made an example [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester82.yaml) using [this workflow implementation](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester82.yaml) with another example for concatenation that can be useful depending on what you want to achieve.